# Nuxt3: Error using nuxt-cookie-control (@dargmuesli/nuxt-cookie-control)

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to use this nuxt-cookie-consent package:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dargmuesli/nuxt-cookie-control
- https://nuxt.com/modules/cookie-control
- https://gitlab.com/broj42/nuxt-cookie-control

I am using **Nuxt 3.3.1**

There is also a playground example on how to use the dependency here: https://stackblitz.com/github/dargmuesli/nuxt-cookie-control?file=playground%2Fapp.vue

As instructed in the README.md I have installed the package and changed my **nuxt.config.ts** to this:

```
// nuxt.config.ts
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    ssr: true,
    css: [
        'vuetify/styles',
        '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css',
    ],
    vite: {
        // @ts-ignore
        // curently this will lead to a type error, but hopefully will be fixed soon #justBetaThings
        ssr: {
            noExternal: ['vuetify'], // add the vuetify vite plugin
        },
    },
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
    },
    modules: [
        async (options, nuxt) => {
            // @ts-ignore
            nuxt.hooks.hook('vite:extendConfig', config => config.plugins.push(
                vuetify()
            ))
        },
        ['nuxt-cookie-control', {
            //default css (true)
            //if css is set to false, you will still be able to access
            //your color variables (example. background-color: var(--cookie-control-barBackground))
            css: true,
        
            //enable or disable css variables polyfill
            cssPolyfill: true,
        
            //in case you have subdomains (shop.yourdomain.com)
            domain: 'yourdomain.com',
        
            //if you want to tree-shake locales set locales you want to use
            locales: ['en', 'de'],
        
            //modal opener (cookie control)
            controlButton: true,
        
            //block iframes to prevent them from adding additional cookies
            blockIframe: true,
        
            //position of cookie bar:
            //'top-left', 'top-right', 'top-full',
            //'bottom-left', 'bottom-right', 'bottom-full'
            barPosition: 'bottom-full',
        
            dashInDescription: true,
        
            //default colors
            //if you want to disable colors set colors property to false
            colors: {
              barTextColor: '#fff',
              modalOverlay: '#000',
              barBackground: '#000',
              barButtonColor: '#000',
              modalTextColor: '#000',
              modalBackground: '#fff',
              modalOverlayOpacity: 0.8,
              modalButtonColor: '#fff',
              modalUnsavedColor: '#fff',
              barButtonHoverColor: '#fff',
              barButtonBackground: '#fff',
              modalButtonHoverColor: '#fff',
              modalButtonBackground: '#000',
              controlButtonIconColor: '#000',
              controlButtonBackground: '#fff',
              barButtonHoverBackground: '#333',
              checkboxActiveBackground: '#000',
              checkboxInactiveBackground: '#000',
              modalButtonHoverBackground: '#333',
              checkboxDisabledBackground: '#ddd',
              controlButtonIconHoverColor: '#fff',
              controlButtonHoverBackground: '#000',
              checkboxActiveCircleBackground: '#fff',
              checkboxInactiveCircleBackground: '#fff',
              checkboxDisabledCircleBackground: '#fff',
            },
        
            //default texts
            text: {
              barTitle: 'Cookies',
              barDescription: 'We use our own cookies and third-party cookies so that we can show you this website and better understand how you use it, with a view to improving the services we offer. If you continue browsing, we consider that you have accepted the cookies.',
              acceptAll: 'Accept all',
              declineAll: 'Delete all',
              manageCookies: 'Manage cookies',
              unsaved: 'You have unsaved settings',
              close: 'Close',
              save: 'Save',
              necessary: 'Necessary cookies',
              optional: 'Optional cookies',
              functional: 'Functional cookies',
              blockedIframe: 'To see this, please enable functional cookies',
              here: 'here'
            }
        }]     
    ],
    head: {
        link: [
          { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" },
          {
            rel: "stylesheet",
            href: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap",
          },
        ],
    },
})
```

I have also changed my **app.vue** to this:
[image]

When starting up my app, it says it can't find module nuxt-cookie-control, but it is listed in the dependencies:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, and how come it can't find the module even though it is installed as a dependency? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the playground](https://github.com/dargmuesli/nuxt-cookie-control/blob/92699a1dbed5e3a76821403499b38a8c89c8f3c3/playground/nuxt.config.ts); make sure to use the full module name:

```
// `nuxt.config.ts`
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        '@dargmuesli/nuxt-cookie-control'
    ],

    cookieControl: {
        // options
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh boy, did I make a simple mistake... Thanks!